# what methods use defined permissions in androidManifest file?

Tags: android, android-permissions

In androidManifest file, there's uses-permission tag, how to know what method uses the defined perrmission in this tag.

Comment: Do you mean you wanna get the permission use in your app or all apps installed on the device ?

Comment: only in my app.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 try {
        PackageInfo pkgInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        String[] requestedPermissions = pkgInfo.requestedPermissions;

        if (requestedPermissions == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No declared permissions");
        } else {
            String permissionsText = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < pkgInfo.requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
                permissionsText += requestedPermissions[i] + "\n";
            }
            Log.d(TAG, permissionsText);
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Package Not Found");
    }
```

#### So How the permission working :

> If Signature is specified, access is granted if a requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. The level SignatureOrSystem grants access to applications that are in the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificates as those in the system image.

**take a look at following links :**

- [Manifest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) official documentation
- [permission-tracking.pdf](https://www.se.jku.at/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2012.permission-tracking.pdf)

Comment: this doesn't specify what method uses the permission. I need some kind of mapping between the permissions in uses-permission and the method that uses it